# MediaElement.js dynamic content not working in IE9

Tags: dynamic, internet-explorer-9, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to use MediaElement.js on a site and everything works great in every browser but IE, most specifically IE9 (I'm not too concerned with supporting below IE9 at the moment).  I'm populating the ME dynamically which I've read can cause problems in IE specifically, but I'm just not sure if there is a workaround.  The reason I'm doing it this way is because this is a portfolio site where all project data gets loaded through a getJSON call and once loaded all projects get populated with their appropriate data and created on the fly.  There are several video projects.  I've dumbed the code down to an example outside of my project which essentially goes through this same behavior.  If I just write the HTML out and control in JS it works but when I create the HTML through JS and then try to play I get the error log (in the creation of ME player in the code).  Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
            var details = {
                    width: 640,
                    height: 480,
                    src: 'work/television/1'
                },
                $body = $('body'),
                $vid = $('<video width="' + details.width + '" height="' + details.height + '" preload="none" id="vidPlayer1"></video>'),
                $mp4 = $('<source src="' + details.src + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" title="mp4">'),
                $webm = $('<source src="' + details.src + '.webm" type="video/webm" title="webm">'),
                $ogg = $('<source src="' + details.src + '.ogv" type="video/ogg" title="ogg">'),
                $flash = $('<object width="' + details.width + '" height="' + details.height + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="swf/flashmediaelement.swf"><param name="movie" value="swf/flashmediaelement.swf"><param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=' + details.src + '.mp4"></object>'),
                $error = $('<p>The available video formats are not supported by your browser. :(</p>'),
                $controls = $('<div class="videoControls playBtn"></div>');

            $body.append($controls);

            $vid.append($mp4);
            $vid.append($webm);
            $vid.append($ogg);
            $vid.append($flash);
            $vid.insertAfter($controls);

            var vidPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#vidPlayer1', {
                features: [],
                // mode: 'shim',
                pluginPath: 'swf/',
                success: function(mediaElement) {
                    console.log('success', mediaElement);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('Error loading player.  Please try again.');
                }
            });

            $body.on('click', function(evt) {
                vidPlayer.play();
            });
        });
```

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.  for anyone interested, had to combine my appends into one call so $vid became:

```
$vid = $('<video width="' + details.width + '" height="' + details.height + '" preload="none" id="vidPlayer-' + row + '-' + slide + '"><source src="' + details.src + '.mp4" type="video/mp4" title="mp4"><source src="' + details.src + '.webm" type="video/webm" title="webm"><source src="' + details.src + '.ogv" type="video/ogg" title="ogg"><p>The available video formats are not supported by your browser. :(</p></video>')
```

just had to put it all in one statement and IE9 recognized it properly.  The issue was by appending as I was doing the source variables never got appended and thus IE didn't know what the source of my video was.

Hope this helps someone in the future.